# Unwanted {} at the beginning of the JSON output

Tags: php, json

I am getting {} in the beginning of the json output from php code. How to eliminate this? am accessing this JSON output from php in android. when the android code executes,it shows error in fetching data from php code.

This is my php code.

```
        <?php

        include_once "/db_connect.php";
        $db = new DB_CONNECT();
        $head='0';

        if(empty($head)){

            for($head=1;$head<20;$head++){

                if(!empty($head)){

                $response["abc"] = array();


            $flatp=mysql_query("SELECT co.id,co.user_id,co.cat_id,co.flatP,hds.HeadName,co.offer_name,u.shop_name,co.cost FROM abc co INNER JOIN categories ct ON ct.id=co.cat_id INNER JOIN 
                xyz u ON u.id=co.user_id INNER JOIN heads hds ON hds.id=ct.Head_id 
                 WHERE ct.Head_id='$head' AND ct.id=co.cat_id AND co.user_id=u.id ORDER BY co.flatP DESC LIMIT 1");

        if (mysql_num_rows($flatp) >0) {


        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($flatp)) {  
         $recp = array();

           $recp["HeadName"]= $row["HeadName"];
          $recp["offer_name1"]=$row["offer_name"];
         $recp["shop_name1"]=$row['shop_name'];
         $recp["cost1"]=$row['cost'];

        $head_id=$row['user_id'];
        //$recp["$head_id"]='user_id';

        $imageurl='../local_offers_app/trunk/offer_images/'.$head_id.'/'.$row['id'].'.jpg';

        $img=stripslashes($imageurl);
        array_push($response["abc"], $recp);

        }
        }

        $buyget=mysql_query("SELECT co.id,co.user_id,co.cat_id,co.offer_name,co.cost,u.shop_name, CASE WHEN buy>'get' THEN buy
                else 'get'  END as buy FROM abc co INNER JOIN categories ct ON ct.id=co.cat_id INNER JOIN xyz u ON u.id=co.user_id 
                WHERE ct.Head_id='$head' AND ct.id=co.cat_id ORDER BY co.buy DESC LIMIT 1");

        if(mysql_num_rows($buyget) >0) {

         while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($buyget)) {
            $recp = array();

        $recp["offer_name2"]=$row["offer_name"];
         $recp["shop_name2"]=$row['shop_name'];
         $recp["cost2"]=$row['cost'];

        array_push($response["abc"], $recp);

        }
        }

        $buygetamt=mysql_query("SELECT a.id,a.user_id,a.cat_id,a.offer_name,a.cost,u.shop_name,a.buyqnt, 
        SUM(IF(a.cost<b.cost,1,0)) A,
        SUM(IF(a.buyqnt>b.buyqnt,1,0)) B
        FROM abc a JOIN abc b ON a.cost<b.cost AND a.buyqnt>b.buyqnt
         LEFT OUTER JOIN abc c ON a.cost=c.cost AND
         a.id>c.id AND b.id<c.id INNER JOIN categories ct ON ct.id=a.cat_id INNER JOIN xyz u ON u.id=a.user_id WHERE 
         ct.Head_id='$head' AND c.id IS NULL GROUP BY a.cost ORDER BY buyqnt DESC LIMIT 1");

         if(mysql_num_rows($buygetamt) >0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($buygetamt)) {
            $recp = array();
           $recp["offer_name3"]=$row["offer_name"];
         $recp["shop_name3"]=$row['shop_name'];
        $recp["cost3"]=$row['cost'];
        array_push($response["abc"], $recp);

        }
        }

        $buygetp=mysql_query("SELECT a.id,a.user_id,a.cat_id,a.buyqnt,a.buyqntP,a.offer_name,a.cost,u.shop_name, 
        SUM(IF(a.buyqnt<b.buyqnt,1,0)) A,
        SUM(IF(a.buyqntP>b.buyqntP,1,0)) B
        FROM abc a JOIN abc b ON a.buyqnt<b.buyqnt AND a.buyqntP>b.buyqntP LEFT OUTER
        JOIN abc c ON a.buyqnt=c.buyqnt AND a.id>c.id AND b.id<c.id INNER JOIN categories 
        ct ON ct.id=a.cat_id INNER JOIN xyz u ON u.id=a.user_id WHERE ct.Head_id='$head' AND c.id IS NULL GROUP BY 
        a.buyqntP ORDER BY buyqntP DESC LIMIT 1");

        if(mysql_num_rows($buygetp) >0) {

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($buygetp)) {

            $recp = array();
        $recp["offer_name4"]=$row["offer_name"];
         $recp["shop_name4"]=$row['shop_name'];
        $recp["cost4"]=$row['cost'];

        array_push($response["abc"], $recp);

        }

        }

        $upto=mysql_query("SELECT a.id,a.user_id,a.cat_id,a.offer_name,a.cost,u.shop_name,a.upto, 
        SUM(IF(a.cost<b.cost,1,0)) A,
        SUM(IF(a.upto>b.upto,1,0)) B
        FROM abc a JOIN abc b ON  a.upto>b.upto LEFT OUTER JOIN abc c 
        ON a.cost=c.cost AND a.id>c.id AND b.id<c.id INNER JOIN categories ct ON ct.id=a.cat_id
         INNER JOIN xyz u ON u.id=a.user_id WHERE ct.Head_id='$head' AND c.id IS NULL GROUP BY a.upto ORDER BY upto DESC LIMIT 1");

        if(mysql_num_rows($upto) >0) {

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($upto)) {
            $recp = array();
        $recp["offer_name5"]=$row["offer_name"];
        $recp["shop_name5"]=$row['shop_name'];
        $recp["cost5"]=$row['cost'];
        array_push($response["abc"], $recp);

        }
        }       
        }
            $object = (object) array_filter((array) $response);
            $result = json_encode($object);
            echo $result;
                }
            }


        ?>
```

Comment: by modifying the php code.

Comment: Use array_filter() before serializing the data.

Comment: It seems that you json_encode multiple dictionaries. Fix this in the generating code.

Comment: The JSON dosn't look valid once you've added indentation to make it look clearer.

Comment: i have 5 different queries with different result set and am generating single response code from all this 5 result set. is it possible..?

Comment: $object = (object) array_filter((array) $response);
 $result = json_encode($object);  i have used array_filter

Comment: i have put this code into for loop and printing this final response code. please help

Comment: nobody can help you without seeing your php code. Please modify your question and post the relevant php code.

Comment: Don't use mysql_ functions since those are deprecated (!!!!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you did this:

```
$object = (object) array_filter((array) $response); 
$result = json_encode($object);
```

1. you dont need to cast as object before json encoding if your array is associative because json_encode will put associative arrays always into an object
2. array_filter removes all entries from array equal to false (an empty array is not false)

so you should add a custom callback to your filter:

```
function notemptyarray($var) {
    return is_array($var) && count($var) > 0;
} 

$arr = array_filter((array) $response, "notemptyarray");
$result = json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: thanks you @steven.. i did it the way u explained. thank again.

Answer (score 0):

solved.

removed the 'object' and used only 'array_filter'.

Answer (score 0):

this is what i did..

instead of

$object = (object) array_filter((array) $response); 
$result = json_encode($object);

i changed it like..

$object = array_filter((array) $response);

```
        $result = json_encode($object);

        echo trim($result,'[ ]');
```

and it worked.